# How to ask the another question within the less than 20 minute on the StackOverflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, asking-questions, rate-limiting

TO ask a another question within 20 minute  on the Stack overflow not possible,

Comment: Well this  is not bug at all.

Comment: AKA "How can I game the system so I can get around posting restrictions".

Comment: 20 minutes isn't that long. My advice would be to spend the time doing research, so you can post a good question. Most of the time, proper research takes a _lot_ more than 20 minutes.

Comment: If you have any idea abaut these question then only send the comment otherwize dont give the - ve marking

Comment: You are not understanding what i told you dont give the -ve marking ok..

Comment: Shaikh: if you think you've been mis-understood, edit your question to clarify it. Insulting people is a losing strategy.

Comment: What part of your question do you think has been misunderstood? And what does "-ve marking" mean?

Comment: @Cody Gray means you will give the -ve marking ,what i do you see

Comment: No one knows what "the -ve marking" is.

Comment: @CodyGray - I think he means down votes

Comment: You've only asked 2 questions ever and the last one was a week ago, which is quite a bit longer than 20 minutes. What's the problem here?

Comment: Asking people not to downvote you ("don't give the -ve marking") is probably the surest way to get downvoted!

Comment: ... except for asking people to upvote you. That'll get you downvotes too :)

Comment: In maths -ve is the Adjective for negative.

Comment: @michael k thx i not no it wuz abbrev

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible, and quite by design.

20 minutes is not enough time at all to research your problem, attempt solving it yourself, and formulate a good, clear, concise and precise Stack Overflow question.

Spend more time on your problem, and reading/understanding the answers you received on your other questions.

Comment: Notepad to the rescue.

Comment: Perhaps if [he spent more time caring about the title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856762/java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to#comment26069248_17856762), he wouldn't be able to write questions so quickly.